# Add custom header to apollo client polling request

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I am using the `apollo-client` library to query data from my `Graphql` server.  Some of the queries are sent to the server every 5 seconds through apollo polling ability.

Is there a generic way to add a custom header to all requests that are sent by my polling client?

Comment: I deleted my answer so that others see this as unanswered.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## Two Solutions

There are two ways to do that. One is **quick and easy** and will work for a specific query with some limitation, and the other is a **general solution** that is safer and can work for multiple queries.

### Quick and Easy Solution

**Advantages**

- it's quick
- and... easy

When you configure your query you can configure it using its `options` field, that has a `context` field. The value of `context` will be processed by the network chain. The `context` itself is not sent to the server, but if you add a `headers` field to it, it will be used in the HTTP request.

**Example**:

```
const someQuery = graphql(gql`query { ... }`, {
  options: { 
    context: { 
      headers: { 
        "x-custom-header": "pancakes"  // this header will reach the server
      } 
    },
    // ... other options  
  }
})
```

### General Solution using a Network Link middleware

With Apollo you can add an Apollo Link that will act as a middleware and add a custom header to the request based on the `context` that was set by your query operation.

From the docs:

> Apollo Client has a pluggable network interface layer, which can let
>   you configure how queries are sent over HTTP

Read more about [Apollo Link, the network link and Middleware concepts](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/network-layer/).

**Advantages**:

- The middleware's logic can be used by any graphql operation (you set the condition)
- Your queries don't need to "care" or know about HTTP headers
- You can do more processing before deciding if and what headers to add to the request.
- and more..

**Setting the context**

Same as the quick and easy solution, only this time we don't set the `headers` directly:

```
 {
   options: { 
     context: { 
       canHazPancakes: true //this will not reach the server
     }
   }
 }
```

**Adding the middleware**

Apollo has a specific middleware for setting the context `apollo-link-context` (the same can be achieved with a more general middleware).

```
import {setContext} from 'apollo-link-context'

//... 

const pancakesLink = setContext((operation, previousContext) => { 
  const { headers, canHazPancakes } = previousContext
  if (!canHazPancakes) { 
    return previousContext
  }

  return {
    ...previousContext,
    headers: {    
      ...headers,
      "x-with-pancakes": "yes" //your custom header
    }
  }
})
```

Don't forget to concat it to the network chain somewhere before your http link

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  // ...
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    pancakesLink,
    <yourHttpLink>
  ])
})
```

There is another useful example in the docs: [using a middleware for authentication](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/network-layer/#middleware).

**That's it!** You should get some pancakes from the server now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, but how to setContext if the app has been initialized already and ApolloClient has already been created?

Comment: This is my question as well. The middleware doesn't seem capable of dynamic headers... hopefully I'm wrong? Also how would I go about implementing this within a <Query> component?

Comment: Can you please provide documentation link for the Quick and Easy Solution? I can't get it to work.

Comment: Hi, Just to note on the quick and easy solution - I didnt need the options property - just the context and below worked for me

Answer (score 12):

Tal Z's answer is very good. However, I thought I'd just paste how to implement the two methods he's listed for those using Angular.

**Adding the header for each individual apollo call**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Pineapples, Pineapple } from './models/pineapples';

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
  }

  callGraphQLQuery() {

    const token = this.localStorageService.get('loginToken');
    this.apollo
      .watchQuery<Pineapples>({

        query: gql`
        {
          pineapples{
            id
            name
          }
        }
      `, 
       context: {
           headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token),
         }
      })
      .valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
        // handle results here
      });


  }

}
```

**Adding the header in the middleware**

```
const uri = 'https://localhost:5001/graphql'; 

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, localStorage: LocalStorageService) {

  const http = httpLink.create({ uri });

  const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    // Get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    const token = localStorage.get('loginToken');

    // Use the setContext method to set the HTTP headers.
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        'Authorization': token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
      }
    });

    // Call the next link in the middleware chain.
    return forward(operation);
  });

  return {
    link: authLink.concat(http),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink, LocalStorageService],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

Comment: why set cookie in localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

Following Diskdrive's step, I will do same for getServerSideProps of nextjs

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const cookies = context.req.headers.cookie;
  const token = getCookie("tokenId", cookies);

  const { data } = await client2.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        me {
          firstName
          sureName
        }
      }
    `,
      context: {
        headers: {
          authorization: token,
        },
      },
  });

 
  return {
    props: {
      dataFromServer: data,
    },
  };
}
```